# GeoJSON + Googlemaps: Uncaught TypeError. Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: google-maps, geojson

This problem is a result of me attempting to load local GeoJSON files by using google maps api:

```js
var turMap;

/*  Konstruer kart  */
function initMap() {
  turMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('hike-map'),
  {
    zoom: 13,
    center:
    {
      lat: 60.3913, lng: 5.3221
    }
  }
);
}

var vidden = {
   "_comment":"https://www.ut.no/tur/2.3909/",
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[
      {
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{
            "name":"Enkel søndagstur over Knatten til Skomakerdiket"
         },
         "geometry":{
            "type":"LineString",
            "coordinates":[
               [
                  5.35519746050418,
                  60.3872017305813
               ],
               [
                  5.35670091445063,
                  60.3867486150925
               ],
               [
                  5.35761580400357,
                  60.3868517763203
               ],
               [
                  5.35857549505049,
                  60.3867100104639
               ],
               [
                  5.35943664537779,
                  60.3869122352666
               ],
               [
                  5.35955799271027,
                  60.387082223776
               ],
               [
                  5.35939343468918,
                  60.3871908425067
               ],
               [
                  5.35890148679304,
                  60.387223934485
               ],
               [
                  5.35899927187223,
                  60.3873190872322
               ],
               [
                  5.35911997128258,
                  60.3872992066534
               ],
               [
                  5.35924603511103,
                  60.3872793260626
               ],
               [
                  5.35980661681649,
                  60.3872793260626
               ],
               [
                  5.36016319242197,
                  60.3872608916251
               ],
               [
                  5.36032061632833,
                  60.3873104320628
               ],
               [
                  5.36050429531247,
                  60.387371604483
               ],
               [
                  5.360628336676,
                  60.3873918220575
               ],
               [
                  5.36093248882549,
                  60.3874414457312
               ],
               [
                  5.3609065184147,
                  60.3876065967871
               ],
               [
                  5.36088823294143,
                  60.3877239403942
               ],
               [
                  5.36100196340622,
                  60.3878771435906
               ],
               [
                  5.36100645796983,
                  60.3879368221347
               ],
               [
                  5.36084925913753,
                  60.3878745218996
               ],
               [
                  5.36067957899846,
                  60.3877734031434
               ],
               [
                  5.36037473303274,
                  60.3876893309108
               ],
               [
                  5.36020567140545,
                  60.3876951972014
               ],
               [
                  5.36004689829025,
                  60.3877384787589
               ],
               [
                  5.35990531555009,
                  60.3877900807977
               ],
               [
                  5.35970469291076,
                  60.3878632007089
               ],
               [
                  5.35958667566894,
                  60.3879274270728
               ],
               [
                  5.35964244912456,
                  60.3880010719457
               ],
               [
                  5.35986897808736,
                  60.3880414542983
               ],
               [
                  5.35991775456087,
                  60.3880828140702
               ],
               [
                  5.35990595412759,
                  60.3881508870824
               ],
               [
                  5.35971677248081,
                  60.3881944171215
               ],
               [
                  5.35962959101481,
                  60.3882481594067
               ],
               [
                  5.35966450957461,
                  60.388295101418
               ],
               [
                  5.35980929902567,
                  60.3883965964427
               ],
               [
                  5.35979588798004,
                  60.3884204523315
               ],
               [
                  5.35952766706835,
                  60.3882786420678
               ],
               [
                  5.35947670509512,
                  60.3882932207212
               ],
               [
                  5.35961012962417,
                  60.388430009883
               ],
               [
                  5.35959085670546,
                  60.3884376456311
               ],
               [
                  5.35931577254806,
                  60.3883223780093
               ],
               [
                  5.35924871732012,
                  60.3883382819733
               ],
               [
                  5.35931040812989,
                  60.3884853932743
               ],
               [
                  5.3592513995293,
                  60.3884973211886
               ],
               [
                  5.35916264968698,
                  60.3884540045809
               ],
               [
                  5.35907437372753,
                  60.3883647885633
               ],
               [
                  5.35904486942728,
                  60.3883475592823
               ],
               [
                  5.35900195408141,
                  60.3883767165218
               ],
               [
                  5.35910119581869,
                  60.3885092490985
               ],
               [
                  5.3591386257183,
                  60.3885583726119
               ],
               [
                  5.35908196209129,
                  60.3885704329673
               ],
               [
                  5.35894620842929,
                  60.3885035559584
               ],
               [
                  5.35886228492334,
                  60.3884152834181
               ],
               [
                  5.35882224607055,
                  60.3883793671786
               ],
               [
                  5.35872928470851,
                  60.3884264153946
               ],
               [
                  5.35863894796079,
                  60.3885366948555
               ],
               [
                  5.35861591813045,
                  60.3886279625097
               ],
               [
                  5.3586237625958,
                  60.3887213000994
               ],
               [
                  5.35857548283175,
                  60.3887345532409
               ],
               [
                  5.35843869016676,
                  60.3886629862119
               ],
               [
                  5.35830033801165,
                  60.3885456156489
               ],
               [
                  5.35826931363943,
                  60.388535679259
               ],
               [
                  5.35820265576441,
                  60.3886219013646
               ],
               [
                  5.35805781647216,
                  60.3888246744614
               ],
               [
                  5.35795228367148,
                  60.3888479950817
               ],
               [
                  5.35773448004984,
                  60.3888611259589
               ],
               [
                  5.35752942127604,
                  60.3888578072007
               ],
               [
                  5.35741052207952,
                  60.3888939131126
               ],
               [
                  5.35730529734881,
                  60.3889417982106
               ],
               [
                  5.35721023839111,
                  60.3890950366269
               ],
               [
                  5.35704124541559,
                  60.3891737630509
               ],
               [
                  5.35669834230404,
                  60.3893049142513
               ],
               [
                  5.35631295050714,
                  60.3894382286246
               ],
               [
                  5.35596590981161,
                  60.3894729951359
               ],
               [
                  5.3557390862174,
                  60.3895337840945
               ],
               [
                  5.35548077502735,
                  60.3896513523287
               ],
               [
                  5.35524848329541,
                  60.3897928968963
               ],
               [
                  5.3551725128766,
                  60.389902771665
               ],
               [
                  5.35516519442244,
                  60.3899140075906
               ],
               [
                  5.35511811527969,
                  60.3900094802549
               ],
               [
                  5.35496024228162,
                  60.3900803107588
               ],
               [
                  5.35479154910827,
                  60.3901065741121
               ],
               [
                  5.35459480127241,
                  60.3901132301849
               ],
               [
                  5.35446534733726,
                  60.3901144123134
               ],
               [
                  5.35425980836219,
                  60.3902228467399
               ],
               [
                  5.354050596051,
                  60.3903156143406
               ],
               [
                  5.35381724385782,
                  60.3903726000216
               ],
               [
                  5.35384138373989,
                  60.3903964544633
               ],
               [
                  5.35409619360596,
                  60.3904110321685
               ],
               [
                  5.35414312554375,
                  60.3904247905324
               ],
               [
                  5.3541256979063,
                  60.3904507895143
               ],
               [
                  5.35357079991434,
                  60.3905693765085
               ],
               [
                  5.35359231501038,
                  60.3906186898829
               ],
               [
                  5.35364290026514,
                  60.390684031632
               ],
               [
                  5.35358657387373,
                  60.390715837246
               ],
               [
                  5.352424685684,
                  60.3908859803492
               ],
               [
                  5.35215090291057,
                  60.3909821513972
               ],
               [
                  5.35212004640185,
                  60.3911201865863
               ],
               [
                  5.35206720953547,
                  60.3912376319067
               ],
               [
                  5.35228302024277,
                  60.3913201380061
               ],
               [
                  5.35238762639833,
                  60.3913824227539
               ],
               [
                  5.35232496718828,
                  60.391830155205
               ],
               [
                  5.35161857779009,
                  60.3926489268973
               ],
               [
                  5.35130898502228,
                  60.3933025943679
               ],
               [
                  5.35102544260075,
                  60.3935817190184
               ],
               [
                  5.3506775271604,
                  60.3938290387343
               ],
               [
                  5.35101145465887,
                  60.3939989109631
               ],
               [
                  5.3513235667801,
                  60.3942035483257
               ],
               [
                  5.35185461219244,
                  60.3943132785146
               ],
               [
                  5.35223012146887,
                  60.3942019710294
               ],
               [
                  5.35263556134985,
                  60.3944387124446
               ],
               [
                  5.35292140607504,
                  60.3945545001536
               ],
               [
                  5.35323897353888,
                  60.3946678885561
               ],
               [
                  5.35343692884329,
                  60.3947599508639
               ],
               [
                  5.35359381362774,
                  60.3948589248291
               ],
               [
                  5.35391454879441,
                  60.394891011252
               ],
               [
                  5.35385014482839,
                  60.3950203097078
               ],
               [
                  5.35380648381355,
                  60.3952625992684
               ],
               [
                  5.35346278022312,
                  60.395396205806
               ],
               [
                  5.35307769954992,
                  60.3956118377229
               ]
            ]
         }}
   ]}

turMap.data.addGeoJson(vidden);
```

```css
/***************
ELEMENT STYLING
***************/

body {
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


p, h1, h2{
  margin: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 20%;
  margin-left: 20%;

}

/***************
  STYLING MAPS
***************/

#playground-map {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  content: center;
}

#toilett-map {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  content: center;
}

#railway-map {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  content: center;
}

#hike-map {
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  content: center;
}

/***************
  CLASS STYLING
***************/
.fixedText{
  position: absolute;
  top: 135px;
  right: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}

.localNavPrev{
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.localNavNext{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5%;


}

.infoWindow{
  max-width: 5%;
}

.wallpaper{
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #715f47;

}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #487a8a;
  color: white;
}

.active a:hover not(.active) {
  background-color: #487a8a;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/***************
MEDIA QUERIES
***************/

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}  /*Hides each <a> in the topnav class, except the first child.*/
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }

  #toilett-map{
    max-height: 400px;
  }

  #playground-map{
    max-height: 400px;
  }

  #railway-map{
    max-height: 400px;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Meta Data -->
    <title>
      Oversikt Bergen
    </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">
    <!-- Java Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/hamburgerMenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/tur.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Navigasjon / Meny -->
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a class="active" href="index.html">Oversikt Bergen</a>
      <a href="practical.html">Praktisk</a>
      <a href="recreational.html">Kultur</a>
      <a href="#about">Kontakt</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>


    <div class="center">

      <h1>
        <a>Turer I Bergen</a>
      </h1>

      <img class="localNavPrev" src="img/icons/previous.svg" alt="Naviger turkart tilbake">
      <img class="localNavNext" src="img/icons/next.svg" alt="Naviger turkart frem">




      <p>
        Du har mange muligheter til å benytte deg av et variert friluftsliv i Bergen.
        Bruk pilene til å navigere mellom forskjellige turer i Bergensområde.
      </p>

      <div id="hike-map"></div>

      <!-- Google Map API -->
      <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAY3Sz7Ey7QKva2pJcr9vyPGemTH7mvLF4&callback=initMap&language=no&region=NO">
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need some help with my code. For some reason, the property of "data" is undefined. And I'm struggling with finding out why. I've seen people have similar error codes before, usually because the data isnt parsed propperly. I cannot however find out any syntax errors with my code.

If i import the GeoJSON file only, to googles drag and drop data layer it all works out perfectly. Which is why I find it a little frustrating. Have anyone had any similar issues with this? I'm sorry if this is a noob question, I'm trying to learn :))

Answer (score 1):

Move:

```
 turMap.data.addGeoJson(vidden);
```

Inside the `initMap` function (where the variable `turMap` is defined)

The `initMap` function runs asynchronously after the API has loaded (and after the call to `turMap.data.addGeoJson` in you current code)

```
<script async defer ... &callback=initMap
```

Comment: this was my first thought , but then I saw that turMap is actually defined in the global scope, then he assign turMap = new google.maps.Map inside initMap, If this is actually the fix for this, could you explain why please? I would really appreciate a bit of clarity with that